# BigQuery SQL limit update to one row

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sql-update

I have this `BigQuery` table with three columns and every row can have same values of the previous one.

For example:

```
| col_a | col_b | col_c
+-------+-------+------------
| 123   |   3   | 2019-12-12
| 123   |   3   | 2019-12-12
| 234   |  11   | 2019-10-12
```

Now I want to add new column named col_d with a UUID in it.

The problem is that when I try to execute `UPDATE` command I have no way to update only one row at a time (because some rows have the same values and I want different UUID in each one of them).

Things I tried with no luck :(

**LIMIT**

```
UPDATE table 
SET col_d = GENERATE_UUID() 
LIMIT 1
```

I thought to get all rows and then traverse them with an update command. But there's not LIMIT on UPDATE commands in BigQuery.

**ROW_NUMBER**

```
UPDATE table 
SET col_d = ROW_NUMBER() OVER()
```

But BigQuery doesn't allow to use analytic function in `Update` command

**INSERT**

I can query all rows, and insert them with a UUID and then delete all the old ones that has no UUID. that approach will work and it will be my final gateaway but I believe there's a better way so I'm asking here.

Any other idea or advice will be welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and produces different UUID for each and every row no matter how duplicate they are

```
UPDATE `project.dataset.table`
SET col_d = GENERATE_UUID()
WHERE TRUE
```

Note: based on your "Insert and then Delete" option - I assume that col_d already exists in your table - otherwise you would not be able to do `DELETE FROM table WHERE col_d IS NULL` as you mentioned in your comments

Comment: is the "where true" is where the magic happens? this is what causing the different uuid to be generated?

Comment: in BigQuery WHERE clause is mandatory with UPDATE statement :o)

Answer (score 1):

You can SELECT the data with a UUID as a fourth column (col_d) and then save that data as a new table.

```
SELECT col_ac, col_b, col_c, GENERATE_UUID() AS col_d
FROM table
```

This will generate the output you desire:

```
| col_a | col_b | col_c       | col_d
+-------+-------+-------------+------------------------------------------
| 123   |   3   | 2019-12-12  | e3784e4d-59bb-433b-a9ac-3df318e0f675
| 123   |   3   | 2019-12-12  | 430d034a-6292-4f5e-b1b0-0ee5550af3f6
| 234   |  11   | 2019-10-12  | 3e7e14d2-3077-4030-a704-5a2b7fc3c11e
```

Since BigQuery does not allow adding a column with data like traditional SQL the following should create a new table with the UUID values added.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE table AS 
SELECT *, GENERATE_UUID() AS col_d
FROM table
```

Be warned that the table history may be deleted so back it up first. One should always backup data prior to doing such updates in all cases as undesired outcomes do arise.

Comment: What I did is selecting the data with GENERATE_UUID as you suggested and added it to the table. then I just deleted all rows when the col_d is null.
SQL: 
INSERT INTO table SELECT col_a, col_b, col_c, GENERATE_UUID() as col_d;
DELETE FROM table WHERE col_d IS NULL;

Answer (score 1):

> because some rows have the same values and I want different UUID in each one of them

This should do what you want:

```
UPDATE table 
    SET col_d = GENERATE_UUID()
```

I don't understand why you would be using `limit`, if you want to update all rows.

That said, BigQuery has restrictions on `UPDATE`s, so the `CREATE TABLE` approach suggested by fromthehills seems more appropriate.

Comment: Using your update won't set the same uuid for all rows?

Comment: @Avisho . . . The function should be recalculated on each row.  By the way, this is *exactly* the same answer as the one you accepted, but was done several hours earlier.  (Well, it doesn't have the `where true` but that doesn't seem important to the question.)